# xamarin BindingContext with ViewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm having issue with data binding I have a tabbed page contains two tabs chats and groups.

```xml
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="bashal.MainPage" Title="Bashal"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:bashal.Views"
            xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
                
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
                
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom" >
    
    <local:chatPage Title="chats" />
    <local:groupsPage Title="Groups" NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False" />
</TabbedPage>
```

And the first tab called chat contains this page.

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  x:Class="bashal.Views.chatPage"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:bashal.ViewModels" 
        Title="home" >
        
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <ViewModels:chatPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
        
    <StackLayout>
        <CollectionView>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>    
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And I'm trying to do data binding with this ViewModel class from folder called vaiewModels

```cs
namespace bashal.ViewModels
{
    class chatPageViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<rooms> rooms;
        public chatPageViewModel()
        {
            rooms = new ObservableCollection<rooms>
            {
                new rooms {name = "user1", discrbtion= "welcome"},
                new rooms {name = "user2", discrbtion= "welcome"},
                new rooms {name = "user3", discrbtion= "welcome"},
                new rooms {name = "user4", discrbtion= "welcome"},
                new rooms {name = "user5", discrbtion= "welcome"},
                new rooms {name = "user6", discrbtion= "welcome"}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And this the room class

```cs
public  class rooms
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string discrbtion { get; set; }
}
```

But the data doesn't show what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: well, the first problem is that your `CollectionView` does note have an `ItemsSource` defined, so it has nowhere to get its data from

Comment: as an aside, it's bad practice to use the same names for classes and properties/variables.  It makes your code very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to assign an `ItemsSource`

```
<CollectionView ItemSource="{Binding rooms}" >
```

you can only bind to **public properties**, so `rooms` needs to be a **public property**

```
public ObservableCollection<rooms> rooms { get; set; }
```

Comment: It should be `ItemsSource` not `ItemSource` .  :)